# Running Multiple Nodes for ejabberd server on aws. ec2 instance

Tags: elixir, ejabberd

I have installed elixir with built in ejabberd server on aws instance.

The following are my queries regarding the same:

1. When I start the elixir server via mix command...

   - It is displayed on the console that ejabberd server started on nonode@nohost.
   - I want to change the name of the node.
   - I tried to change the node name using command

`:ejabberd_admin.mnesia_change_nodename('nonode@nohost', 'coolnode@localhost', "/_build/dev/lib/ejabberd/old.backup", "/_build/dev/lib/ejabberd/new.backup")`

But it gives me the error

> {:error, {:EXIT, :function_clause}}

Also I tried

- Getting out of the elixir shell and printing the command:
  iex --sname coolnode@localhost

It changed the node name, but when I restart the elixir server, it is again printed on the console that........ ejabberd server started on nonode@nohost

2. When I install elixir ejabberd server on another aws instance I want to join these 2 nodes.

   - How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change the name of the node.

You can configure the erlang node name in the file ejabberdctl.cfg where it says:

```
ERLANG_NODE=ejabberd@localhost
```

Before doing that, stop ejabberd and delete the Mnesia spool files (which were created using the old node name).

> When I install elixir ejabberd server on another aws instance I want
>   to join these 2 nodes.

Once you can get one ejabberd node running. Install ejabberd in another machine/instance, and configure it with a different erlang node name, probably that will be "ejabberd@machine2".

In one of the machines, execute something like this:

```
ejabberdctl join_cluster ejabberd@theotherone
```